# Random number generation using laplace distribution

Tags: distributions, matlab, random-generation

I am a newbie in stat. I am completing my thesis in [Evolutionary algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm). I have to generate some random numbers from [Laplace distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution). How can I do this using matlab?

An easy and simple explanation would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.